# How to sign an Android application for publishing on playstore

Tags: unity-game-engine

when I try to publish my unity games on google developer, I always have this error:

> Failed to import. You have imported an APK or Android App Bundle that
>   can be debugged. For security reasons, you must disable debugging
>   before the applicable APK or Android App Bundle can be published on
>   Google Play. Learn more about APKs or Android Bundle Bundle packages
>   for which the Debug feature has been enabled.
>   You have imported an APK or an Android App Bundle with a signature in debug mode. You must sign it in output version mode. Learn more about the signature.

I think there are something in maintemplate.gradle to change: 
this is my mainTemplate:

```
 // GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
      flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
      }
   }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
**DEPS**}

android {
    compileSdkVersion **APIVERSION**
    buildToolsVersion '**BUILDTOOLS**'

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion **TARGETSDKVERSION**
        applicationId '**APPLICATIONID**'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress '.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb'
    }

**SIGN**
    buildTypes {

        release {
            // Set minifyEnabled to true if you want to run ProGuard on your project
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debbugable false
            **SIGNCONFIG**
            signingConfig signingConfigs.firstapp
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: There is a lot of tutorial about how to sign an android app. Just google it [Sign app](https://answers.unity.com/questions/326812/signing-android-application.html)

Comment: i think there are something in mainTemplate.gradle to change,

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure your settings are like this -

[image: Example]

Comment: i think there are something in mainTemplate.gradle to change,